# Unexpected zero on posterior density of Dirichlet process mixture

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric, density-estimation, pymc, dirichlet-process

I was reading [this notebook from the PyMC3 documentation](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/dp_mix.html) about Dirichlet Process Mixtures and, on the last figure, the estimated density reaches almost zero for a particular value, despite the histogram showing that many data points fall close to that value. Now, I am wondering:

1. **Why does this zero appear?** If the *expected posterior density* is close to zero, then all the sampled densities must be almost zero, right? Why would this happen, if many data points are close to that value?
2. **Is this a MCMC artifact?** The author of the notebook checked that they are using enough Dirichlet components, but maybe there is some other source of bias?
3. **Is this model misspecification?** I would doubt that, given how flexible Dirichlet processes are supposed to be, but this result seems so odd that I just don't know anymore.

The overall incompatibility between the histogram and the Dirichlet process mixture posterior is very odd to me, but that zero seems to be the bigger issue.